# How to get the values from the Json using Jquery

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery

Hi I'm new to Jquery and i don't know how to use json data. I have a Json which is coming as a response. My success function is

```
success: function(resp)
{
    var x = JSON.stringify(resp);
    alert(x);

}
```

alert is having following JSON

{"xyz":{"abc":[{"action":"fail","result":"xxx"},{"action":"pass","resut":"yyy"}]}}

I want action value alone. How can i get this value from x variable and how can i utilize this value in HTML. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `JSON.stringify()` you are turning it into a string, you want it as an object to access the data. Try this:

```
success: function(resp) {
    alert(resp.xyz.abc[0].action); 
    var x = resp.xyz.abc[0].action  // to use the value in html later on
}
```

If it is returned as a string (I can't tell at this point), you can turn it into an object (as long as it is valid JSON) by using [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: My success function is inside ajax so I'm not getting the expected output after the code you have given . your code is correct but can you tell me if i have this success menthod in $.ajax function your code will work or not and if not is there any other way

Comment: @Sau Have you tried debugging? Are you definitely getting inside the success function? What is `alert`ed? Try console.log'ing `resp` and see what is returned.

Comment: @Sau That's good, it means you are getting the object. Try console.log ing that object and seeing exactly what is inside it. In chrome you can click the arrow next to it (in your console) to expand it and see exactly what it contains

Comment: I'm getting something like object{xyz: Object} if i expand this I'm getting xyz:Object on expanding it abc:array[2] expanding it will give 0:Object  1:Object 2:Object and futher expanding this object will give for 0:Object it give result:"you are fail" and action:fail and so on for others.

Comment: It is also giving some _proto_:Object under 0:Object and if i expand this _proto_:Object it will yield a bunch of things there which are functions and can be expandable..

Comment: @Sau It should work then... what is being alerted when you use my code above?

Comment: Andy thanks for you help i really appriciate but what if I have xyz = xyz-kkk-ll-list and abc as xyz-kkk-ll will it effect the code

Comment: @Sau Can you explain what you mean a bit more?

Comment: because its showing me Uncaught ReferenceError: kkk is not defined

Comment: @Sau What is the entire code you are using? kkk is not part of your object

Comment: sure the json i mention above i have used xyz and abc but in actual i have json like {"xyz-kkk-ll-list":{"xyz-kkk-ll":[{"action":"fail","result":"xxx"},{"action":"pass","resut":"yyy"}]}} so when i use your code it shows an error in console Uncaught ReferenceError: kkk is not defined

Comment: but when i use JSON.stringify(resp) it shows the whole json in alert

Comment: @Sau Ohhh right. That is because you can't use a dash with dot notation (e.g. `var x = resp.xyz-kkk-ll-list.xyz-kkk-ll[0].action`) instead you need to use `resp["xyz-kkk-ll-list"]["xyz-kkk-ll"][0].action`

Comment: now I'm getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xyz-kkk-ll' of undefined

Comment: @Sau Can you make a http://www.jsfiddle.net of your problem? It is hard to troubleshoot without fiddling with the code myself

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(resp)
{
    var x = $.parseJSON(resp);
    var xyz = x.xyz;
    var pass = x.xyz.abc[1].action;
}
```

or you can loop though each of the array by $.each

```
success: function(resp)
{
    var x = $.parseJSON(resp);
    $.each(x.xyz.abc, function(index, element){
        alert('action:' + element.action + ', result:' + element.resut)
    });
}
```

Comment: I have the success function in $.ajax function where i have mention the type as GET, data-type as JSON and username and password to do authentication why I'm not getting the expected output can i use $.parseJSON inside $.ajax method if yes then why it is not working in my case. can you please guide me further

Answer (score 0):

i think, and don't take it personally,that your JSON object is not well organized as an object to get and to have. Action,from my perspective is either fail or success, and reading it, as you saw in the above good answer, will give you exactly what you want.

What's the point in getting a JSON with data structured like you did, with 2 possible answers encoded in it, when there is only one available (either success or fail).